# Convert a decoded Base64 byte string to a vector of bools

Tags: c++, base64

I have a base64 string containing bits, I have alredy decoded it with the code in [here](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/cpp/common/base64.html). But I'm unable to transform the resultant string in bits I could work with. Is there a way to convert the bytes contained in the code to a vector of bools containing the bits of the string?

I have tried converting the char with this code but it failed to conver to a proper char

```
void DecodedStringToBit(std::string const& decodedString, std::vector<bool> &bits) {
    int it = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < decodedString.size(); ++i) {
        unsigned char c = decodedString[i];
        for (unsigned char j = 128; j > 0; j <<= 1) {
            if (c&j) bits[++it] = true;
            else bits[++it] = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with taking one `char` from the encoded `string` and `push_back` it to the `vector<bool>` (and loop over it)?

Comment: the string has the values in bytes, so one char is a byte, i have to get a bit of it, i tried converting it to 8 bits with this code  int it = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i < decodedString.size(); ++i) {
  unsigned char c = decodedString[i];
  for (unsigned char j = 128; j > 0; j <<= 1) {
   if (c&j) bits[++it] = true;
   else bits[++it] = false;
but the result was wrong.

Comment: Can you please add your code in the question body in a formatted way so that it is easier to read?

Answer (score 1):

In OP's code, it is not clear if the vector `bits` is of sufficient size, for example, if it is `resize`d by the caller (It should not be!). If not, then the vector does not have space allocated, and hence `bits[++it]` may not work; the appropriate thing might be to `push_back`. (Moreover, I think the code might need  the post-increment of `it`, i.e. `bits[it++]` to start from `bits[0]`.)

Furthermore, in OP's code, the purpose of `unsigned char j = 128` and `j <<= 1` is not clear. Wouldn't `j` be all zeros after the first iteration? If so, the inner loop would always run for only one iteration.

I would try something like this (not compiled):

```
void DecodedStringToBit(std::string const& decodedString,
                        std::vector<bool>& bits) {
    for (auto charIndex = 0; charIndex != decodedString.size(); ++charIndex) {
        const unsigned char c = decodedString[charIndex];
        for (int bitIndex = 0; bitIndex != CHAR_BIT; ++bitIndex) { 
            // CHAR_BIT = bits in a char = 8
            const bool bit = c & (1 << bitIndex);  // bitwise-AND with mask
            bits.push_back(bit);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While it worked more consistenly than mine it converted the chars to bytes.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is probably 1, likely not what you want.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone: No, I meant CHAR_BIT. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

Your inner `for` loop is botched: it's shifting `j` the wrong way. And honestly, if you want to work with 8-bit values, you should use the proper `<stdint.h>` types instead of `unsigned char`:

```
for (uint8_t j = 128; j; j >>= 1)
    bits.push_back(c & j);
```

Also, remember to call `bits.reserve(decodedString.size() * 8);` so your program doesn't waste a bunch of time on resizing.

---

I'm assuming the bit order is MSB first. If you want LSB first, the loop becomes:

```
for (uint8_t j = 1; j; j <<= 1)
```